# How to play video in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a play/pause button for every video.

When I click on the play button, the last video is always played, and the icon changes on all videos. I try to do that with refs and play() method but every time, whatever video the user selects just the last video is played. Every click event play the last one.

Also, the code for full screen does not work.
This is my code:

```
class Video extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      playing: false,
      videoList: [
        {
          src: 'https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4',
          type: "video/mp4"

        },
        {
          src: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4",
          type: "video/mp4"
        },
        {
          src: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4",
          type: "video/mp4"
        },
        {
          src: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4",
          type: "video/mp4"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  onPlayPauseClick = (index) => (event) => {
    this.setState({
      playing: !this.state.playing
    });
    this.state.playing ? this.video.pause() : this.video.play();
  }

  //     onFullScreenClick = (video) => {
  //         this.setState({ video: video })
  //         if (video.requestFullscreen) {
  //             video.requestFullscreen();
  //         } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  //             video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  //         } else if (video.mozRequestFullscreen) {
  //             video.mozRequestFullscreen();
  //         } else if (video.msRequestFullscreen) {
  //             video.msRequestFullscreen();

  //         }

  //     }
  renderList = () => {
    const { playing } = this.state;
    return this.state.videoList.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <li key={`item_${index}`}>
          <video ref={(video) => { this.video = video; }} src={item.src}></video>
          <img
            src={playing ? "https://icon2.kisspng.com/20180419/pyq/kisspng-computer-icons-arrow-triangle-play-icon-5ad83452103159.1624767815241186100663.jpg" : "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-and-simple-pack-2/512/1_Control_pause-512.png"}
            className="play"
            onClick={this.onPlayPauseClick(index)}
          />
          <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_fullscreen_exit_48px-512.png" className="full" />
        </li>
      )

    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.renderList()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Buttons extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Video />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Video />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's happened because you saved the last video item in `this.video`, after iterating through `videoList` array elements . Try to save ref in `this['video_'+index]=video` instead of `this.video=video`, and start to play with code `this['video_'+index].play()`

Comment: I tried to fix the English and formatting here, but I really don't understand what "after each the array `videoList` is supposed to mean, can you please review and perhaps edit to rephrase? I guess you are trying to say that you are losing track of the index ...?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think you have your ref messed up, you can create a new array of ref and use it with the index

```
constructor () {
  this.ref = [];
}
```

and in your return do something like this

```
return this.state.videoList.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <li key={`item_${index}`}>
      <video ref={(video) => { this.ref.push(video) }} src={item.src}></video>
      <img
        src={playing ? "https://icon2.kisspng.com/20180419/pyq/kisspng-computer-icons-arrow-triangle-play-icon-5ad83452103159.1624767815241186100663.jpg" : "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-and-simple-pack-2/512/1_Control_pause-512.png"}
        className="play"
        onClick={this.onPlayPauseClick(index)}
      />
      <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_fullscreen_exit_48px-512.png" className="full" />
    </li>
  )

});
```

and then you can call your ref inside the play pause method

```
onPlayPauseClick = (index) => (event) => {
    this.setState({
      playing: !this.state.playing
    });
    this.state.playing ? this.ref[index].pause() : this.ref[index].play();
  }
```

For fullscreen I can suggest you don't try to over complicate the things, there is an awesome library for the player you can go with it.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player

Answer (score 0):

Full functioning code for your question.

```
import React from "react";

class Video extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.video = [];
    this.state = {
      playing: [false, false, false, false],
      videoList: [
        {
          src: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4",
          type: "video/mp4"
        },
        {
          src: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4",
          type: "video/mp4"
        },
        {
          src: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4",
          type: "video/mp4"
        },
        {
          src: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4",
          type: "video/mp4"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  onPlayPauseClick = index => event => {
    this.setState(state => {
      state.playing = !state.playing;
      state.playing ? this.video[index].play() : this.video[index].pause();
      return state.playing[index];
    });
  };

  onFullScreenClick = index => event => {
    let video = this.video[index];
    if (video.requestFullscreen) {
      video.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (video.mozRequestFullscreen) {
      video.mozRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (video.msRequestFullscreen) {
      video.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
  };
  renderList = () => {
    const { playing } = this.state;
    return this.state.videoList.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <li key={`item_${index}`}>
          <video
            ref={video => {
              this.video[index] = video;
            }}
            src={item.src}
          />
          <img
            src={
              playing
                ? "https://icon2.kisspng.com/20180419/pyq/kisspng-computer-icons-arrow-triangle-play-icon-5ad83452103159.1624767815241186100663.jpg"
                : "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-and-simple-pack-2/512/1_Control_pause-512.png"
            }
            className="play"
            onClick={this.onPlayPauseClick(index)}
          />
          <img
            src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_fullscreen_exit_48px-512.png"
            className="full"
            onClick={this.onFullScreenClick(index)}
          />
        </li>
      );
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>{this.renderList()}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Video;
```

Answer (score 0):

Im use react-player, where option "controls" - Set to true or false to display native player controls.  look at the "react-player", it has everything you need

```
<ReactPlayer url={'url/to/video'} className={classes.styleView} controls/>
```